# How to post data from a HTML page to a servlet using jQuery/jS

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I am trying to submit a form from a JSP page to a servlet. I am trying to make a dynamic page, where a form opens up on press of a button and send the data when the form is submitted. When the form is submitted the popup form closes and returns to the main page. I have implemented the form, and the popup form closes when i click on post but the data is not sent to the servlet.

Code of form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Technology</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="select">
    <option>Java</option>
    <option>C++</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>Python</option>
    <option>.Net</option>
    <option>Javascript</option>
  </select>
  <br> <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Query</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textArea"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default"
    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="submit" id="pst" class="btn btn-primary"
    data-dismiss="modal">Post</button>
</div>
```

I tried to go to the send to the servlet via different solutions provided over the web, but nothing seems to work.  The function is being called since i tried doing an alert inside the onclick function, the alert did show but nothing else.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: "The function is being called" — What function?

Comment: "the onclick function" — What onclick function?

Comment: You need to provide a real [test case](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You know it, seems to me you are missing the `name` attribute on the form elements.

```
<select class="form-control" id="select"> <!-- no name attr-->
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textArea"></textarea><!-- no name attr-->
```

Whenever you submit a form `name` attributes serializes the form elements with it's value.

Comment: Well , I am trying to get the attributes via the id of field. Rather than actually posting it the conventional way. I dont want to redirtect to another page.

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri — **start** with the [conventional way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and progressively enhance from there.

Comment: Well i Did try the conventional way but that didnt work either. So i thought using jQuery might make it easier, but that didnt work out either